# Retrieve just the intro text in Wikipedia

Tags: java, android, wikipedia, wiki

How can I retrieve just the **intro text** (those few lines at the beginning of each article), using java?
I've seen a question like this here, the problem is that the code was in `PHP` and I need it in java so I can implement it to my android app...

I've tried to search all GitHub for some easy libraries that could help me get what I want and I got no success.

I've also seen that this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?format=json&action=query&prop=extracts&exintro=&explaintext=&titles=Stack%20Overflow shows information about whatever I want to search. I just can't retrieve the data because, as I said, in that question, the code posted was in `PHP`

Comment: So what have you tried, what is not working? Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Carsten updated question! :)

Comment: This library should help: https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-jwpl/

Comment: How do I install it? I've seen that but it isn't installed by the "compile/implementation"

Comment: the documentation is not great in that respect indeed, but here's how to use it as a Maven dependency: https://dkpro.github.io/dkpro-jwpl/DeveloperSetup/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this https://www.mediawiki.org/api/rest_v1/#!/Page_content/get_page_summary_title

Api for accessing content is here , rest you can normally parse the data.
hope this helps.

Comment: Hm, sweet. I just need to figure out how to parse data. I've never done that, i'm new to android programming but I need to make this to a school project ahah

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm this tutorial helped me learn json parsing.... you can try this

Comment: Hm.. thanks! I found some good libraries to parse json. I just need to retrieve that string provided from the website now ahha

Comment: @Anjani Mittal. Thanks for your answer. How to get the content of all the pages of a wikipedia category? Does there exist any way or tool to achieve this?

Comment: you can use this https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Categorymembers @M_S  hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Anjani. What if I need to download the content (text) of all the pages for a wikipedia category and place them separately in a directory?